# deploy elk stack in kubernetes with helm VolumeBinding error

Tags: elasticsearch, kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to deploy elk stack in kubernetes cluster with helm, using [this](https://hub.helm.sh/charts/stable/elastic-stack) chart. When I launch

`helm install elk-stack stable/elastic-stack`

I receive the following message:

```
NAME: elk-stack
LAST DEPLOYED: Mon Aug 24 07:30:31 2020
NAMESPACE: default
STATUS: deployed
REVISION: 1
NOTES:
The elasticsearch cluster and associated extras have been installed.
Kibana can be accessed:

  * Within your cluster, at the following DNS name at port 9200:

    elk-stack-elastic-stack.default.svc.cluster.local

  * From outside the cluster, run these commands in the same shell:

    export POD_NAME=$(kubectl get pods --namespace default -l "app=elastic-stack,release=elk-stack" -o jsonpath="{.items[0].metadata.name}")
    echo "Visit http://127.0.0.1:5601 to use Kibana"
    kubectl port-forward --namespace default $POD_NAME 5601:5601
```

But when I run

```
kubectl get pods
```

the result is:

```
NAME                                              READY   STATUS              RESTARTS   AGE
elk-stack-elasticsearch-client-7fcfc7b858-5f7fw   0/1     Running   0          12m
elk-stack-elasticsearch-client-7fcfc7b858-zdkwd   0/1     Running   1          12m
elk-stack-elasticsearch-data-0                    0/1     Pending   0          12m
elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0                  0/1     Pending   0          12m
elk-stack-kibana-cb7d9ccbf-msw95                  1/1     Running   0          12m
elk-stack-logstash-0                              0/1     Pending   0          12m
```

Using `kubectl describe pods` command, I see that for elasticsearch pods the problem is:

```
 Warning  FailedScheduling  6m29s      default-scheduler  running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "elk-stack-elasticsearch-data-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

and for logstash pods:

```
Warning  FailedScheduling  7m53s      default-scheduler  running "VolumeBinding" filter plugin for pod "elk-stack-logstash-0": pod has unbound immediate PersistentVolumeClaims
```

Output of `kubectl get pv,pvc,sc -A`:

```
NAME                                      CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   RECLAIM POLICY   STATUS        CLAIM                           STORAGECLASS   REASON   AGE
persistentvolume/elasticsearch-data       10Gi       RWO            Retain           Bound         default/elasticsearch-data      manual                  16d

NAMESPACE      NAME                                                                STATUS    VOLUME                   CAPACITY   ACCESS MODES   STORAGECLASS   AGE
default        persistentvolumeclaim/claim1                                        Pending                                                      slow           64m
default        persistentvolumeclaim/data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-data-0           Pending                                                                     120m
default        persistentvolumeclaim/data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0         Pending                                                                     120m
default        persistentvolumeclaim/data-elk-stack-logstash-0                     Pending                                                                     120m
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-data                            Bound     elasticsearch-data       10Gi       RWO            manual         16d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-data-elasticsearch-data-0       Pending                                                                     17d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-data-elasticsearch-data-1       Pending                                                                     17d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-data-quickstart-es-default-0    Pending                                                                     16d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-0   Pending                                                                     17d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-1   Pending                                                                     17d
default        persistentvolumeclaim/elasticsearch-master-elasticsearch-master-2   Pending                                                                     16d

NAMESPACE   NAME                                         PROVISIONER            RECLAIMPOLICY   VOLUMEBINDINGMODE   ALLOWVOLUMEEXPANSION   AGE
            storageclass.storage.k8s.io/slow (default)   kubernetes.io/gce-pd   Delete          Immediate           false                  66m
```

Storage class `slow` and Persistent volume claim `claim1` are my experiments. I create they using `kubectl create` and a yaml file, the others is automatically created by helm (I think).

Output of `kubectl get pvc data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0 -o yaml`:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  creationTimestamp: "2020-08-24T07:30:38Z"
  finalizers:
  - kubernetes.io/pvc-protection
  labels:
    app: elasticsearch
    release: elk-stack
  managedFields:
  - apiVersion: v1
    fieldsType: FieldsV1
    fieldsV1:
      f:metadata:
        f:labels:
          .: {}
          f:app: {}
          f:release: {}
      f:spec:
        f:accessModes: {}
        f:resources:
          f:requests:
            .: {}
            f:storage: {}
        f:volumeMode: {}
      f:status:
        f:phase: {}
    manager: kube-controller-manager
    operation: Update
    time: "2020-08-24T07:30:38Z"
  name: data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0
  namespace: default
  resourceVersion: "201123"
  selfLink: /api/v1/namespaces/default/persistentvolumeclaims/data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0
  uid: de58f769-f9a7-41ad-a449-ef16d4b72bc6
spec:
  accessModes:
  - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 4Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
status:
  phase: Pending
```

Can somebody please help me to fix this problem? Thanks in advance.

Comment: I supposed that is a volume related problem, but i do not know how to fix it.

Comment: Edit the question to add output of `kubectl get pv,pvc,sc -A`

Comment: ok i do it, thanks.

Comment: Problem is PVC are pending. Are you on GKE and intend to use GCE-PD for storage or you want to use `hostPath` volume?

Comment: It's a local cluster for developement and test purposes, so i'd like to use hostPath

Comment: Okay..edit the question to add output of `kubectl describe pvc data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason why pod is pending is below PVCs are pending because corresponding PVs are not created.

```
data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-master-0
data-elk-stack-logstash-0
data-elk-stack-elasticsearch-data-0
```

Since you have mentioned this is for local development you can use [hostPath](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/volumes/#hostpath) volume for the PV. So create PV for each of the pending PVCs using the sample PV below. So you will create 3 PVs in total.

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-master
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 4Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-logstash
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 2Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: elk-data
  labels:
    type: local
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 30Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  hostPath:
    path: "/mnt/data"
```

Comment: ok, i create three pv with correct size but pods is still pending. I also try to delete helm deploy and re-do it, but nothing change.

Comment: elk-data pv status is bound to a pvc named task-pv-claim (a pvc that i create previously), elk-logstash and elk-master status is available.

Comment: no, i have the same problem, pods are still pending

Comment: All the pods and PVC are still pending? What is the current output of `kubectl get pv,pvc,sc -A`

Comment: i have created an answer with the output of the command

Comment: Delete that answer and I have updated the answer with new yamls of PVs.Try that

Comment: i have the same problem.

Comment: `storageClassName` was not needed in pv..removed it and updated the answer..it should now work

Comment: sorry, but, where i can find `storageClassName`?

Comment: Its not needed..did you try the updated yamls in my answer

Comment: same things, now pods are pending, pvs are available and pvcs are pending

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220403/discussion-between-arghya-sadhu-and-pado).